# Where is my Google+ oauth2 state parameter in the redirect uri?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm making an OpenID / oAuth2 login process for a web app I'm building.

I am able to make an authorization request to Google+. There are several parameters returned in my redirect_uri:

```
access_token = averylongstring
token_type = Bearer
expires_in = 3600
id_token = anextremelylongstring
refresh_token = 1/Jo_tXhJtL3sQTBZURWyKWwebQSjxY1Rb-7sflDC74Pw
created = 1370140758
```

Then I perform a cURL GET that looks something like:

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo';
$curl_data = "?access_token=".$tokens['access_token']."&code=".urlencode('xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com')."&client_id=".urlencode('xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com')."&client_secret=".urlencode('xxxxxxxxx')."&redirect_uri=".urlencode('http://www.mydomain.com/oauth2callback.php')."&grant_type=authorization_code";
```

This gives me an id, which I presume is the successful conclusion to my authentication flow.

So, where did I lose my state variable between the

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Foauth2callback.php&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&state={%22cid%22%3A%22%22%2C%22tid%22%3A%221370142477%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22anappname%22%2C%22Provider%22%3A%22%22}
```

...and my redirect_uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are two redirects going to my callback url. In the first redirect, immediately following when the user allows access to their Google information, the url variables "state" and "code" are sent to my callback page. But then another call, the final authentication request, is made from my callback page, and the result of that is just a clean url without a query string.

So, during the first redirect to my callback page, I read the GET variables, and turn them into SESSION variables. Next, a cURL is performed (and I still don't have this part right, as I am making a cURL post to:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

...and my cURL code looks like:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('access_token' => $access_token,
                                                            'code' => $_REQUEST['code'],
                                                            'client_id' => 'myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                                                            'client_secret' => 'mylittlesecret',
                                                            'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.mydomain.com/oauth2callback.php',
                                                            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                                                            'approval_prompt' => 'force')));
```

getting a:

```
{ "error" : "invalid_request" }
```

I really derive no joy in this part of my coding project.